# Linked Folder in a shared folder in Dropbox

Tags: finder, sharing, folders, dropbox, symlink

I have a folder, that I linked with one in Dropbox using:
http://lifehacker.com/5154698/sync-files-and-folders-outside-your-my-dropbox-folder
and was just wondering if that was situated inside a shared folder, would the changes someone else made in the linked folder also automatically get made to the folder on my computer, or would mine overwrite it?

And also, if the other person could link that folder on their computer, whilst mine remained linked, would that be okay, and work properly, so that we would both have the latest files/folders/etc. automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Most file systems know 2 types of linked files: Hard linked files and soft linked files (more [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/185903/1919382) and here on [linuxgazette](http://linuxgazette.net/105/pitcher.html)) By default, OS X and Windows use soft links (alias, symbolic links). Both types of links make it possible to acces the same folder from different locations.

Dropbox will treat each folder (original or linked) as an original folder on your system, as if it is the only folder with that content. Dropbox will not know if a folder is a symbolic link or not.

Modifications to the content of a linked folder will change the contents of that original folder. As I said, dropbox will treat that folder as any original 'normal' folder, so changing the content within dropbox will change the original.

In short. On each system there is only 1 original folder. You can create as many links as you like, the content of that folder only lives once on your system. Altering the content on any location (e.g. dropbox) will change the content of that original folder.

Comment: I tried to create two symbolic links on two different computers, but the second gave ln: 'file location': File exists

Comment: Well, what do you think "'file location': File exists" means? Try an `ls` and you see you have already made that link. For linking in Linux you need askubuntu.com. In short, you need to remove your previous link and create a link like `ln -s /from/this/directory /in/this/directory/`. Note the slashes and the `ln -s` (-s for symbolic). On OS X, an alias is sufficient. No need for `ls -s`.

Comment: So, how would two different computers, both link a folder to a Dropbox folder, so it would sync both automatically?
Sorry if I posted this in the wrong place.

Comment: OK. Your original folder lives in Dropbox. You have a symlink 'A' to that original folder on computer 1. You also have a symlink 'B' to that original folder on computer 2. When you open 'A', you open your dropbox folder. The same is true for 'B'. So if you add something to 'A', it is added to the original dropbox folder, and therefor also added to 'B'. Just try it and you'll see that it works. Read: http://lifehacker.com/5154698/sync-files-and-folders-outside-your-my-dropbox-folder

Comment: I just learned that an alias does NOT work. You need an `ln -s`.

Comment: I did try using ln -s, but not with the original folder living in dropbox, but with the original folder(s) living in Documents/folder/ on both the computers. So, I assume there's no way to have both linked, with the original folders outside, only one computer can do that, whilst the other has it linked as Dropbox as the original?

Comment: Mightbe we can continue this conversation in the chat. But for now. I have a bin folder located in my dropbox. I have linked this bin folder on multiple computers (>3). `ln -s ~/Dropbox/bin ~/bin`. From Dropbox to the local computer. Just try it out.